# Search query with mongodb returns one result using $or

Tags: javascript, regex, express, mongoose

I am trying to query my MongoDB with javascript but I seem to get one result when I'm supposed to using the `$or`.

I am meant to receive a string form the frontend. My logic was to `split` the string by spaces and search if the string matches any of the skill, location, and name in the database. For example, if a user searches PHP it should bring all users with `PHP` as a skill even if the user has another skill. Below is the code

**data**

```
{
    "_id":"1",
    "skills": ["PHP"],
    "name":"You"
}
{
    "_id":"2",
    "skills": ["PHP", "Javascript"],
    "name":"Me"
}
```

**the code**

```
exports.search = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const escapeChar = escapeString(req.body.query);
    const searchQueries = escapeChar.split(' ');
    let result;
    for (let i in searchQueries) {
      const ret = async () => {
        const pattern = new RegExp(searchQueries[i], 'gi');
        const user = await User.find({
          $or: [{ name: pattern }, { skills: pattern }],
        });
        return user;
      };
      result = await ret();
    }
    if (result.length > 0) {
      return res.json(sendResponse(httpStatus.OK, 'User found', result));
    }
    return res.json(sendResponse(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 'User not found'));
  } catch (error) {
      next(error);
  }  
};
```

Say I search `PHP`, I should get both users. This works.

But if I search with 'PHP me' i get

```
{
    "_id":"2",
    "skills ["PHP", "Javascript"],
    "name":"Me"
}
```

instead of both users since the both have `php` in their skills array. Please, what could be the issue and how do i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `$regex` in your query.

```
db.getCollection('tests').find({
    $or: [{
        name: {
            $regex: /Me$/
        }
    }, {
        skills: {
            $regex: /PHP$/
        }
    }]
});
```

Above query will give you a desire result.

Comment: Doesn't work. If I search "PHP javascript", I still get only the data with both PHP and javascript in the skill instead of both user since they both have PHP in skill

Comment: I noticed if i search "javascript php",both result come out but if i search "php javascript" only the user with skill of php and javascript come

Comment: Why not you try this query on robo3t or any other tool

Answer (score 0):

Because you reassign your `result` in the loop so only the result of the last query come.

You can solve your problem with one query using regex:

```
exports.search = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const escapeChar = escapeString(req.body.query);
    const searchQueries = escapeChar.split(' ');

    const pattern = new RegExp(`(${searchQueries.join("|")})`, 'i');
    const users = await User.find({
      $or: [{ name: pattern }, { skills: pattern }],
    });

    // In case the above not works
    const pattern = new RegExp(`(${searchQueries.join("|")})`);
    const users = await User.find({
      $or: [
        {name: {$regex: pattern, $options: "i" }}, 
        {skills: {$regex: pattern, $options: "i" }}
      ],
    });

    if (users.length > 0) {
      return res.json(sendResponse(httpStatus.OK, 'User found', users));
    }
    return res.json(sendResponse(httpStatus.NOT_FOUND, 'User not found'));
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }  
};
```